# Decompose $D_n$-module $L(\lambda)$ as $B_{(n-1)}$-module

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras

The Lie algebra of type $B_{(n-1)}$ can be got by taking the fixed point subalgebra of the diagram automorphism of $D_n$.
So we can restrict the highest weight module $L(\lambda)$ of $D_n$ to $B_{(n-1)}$. How does it decompose as $B_{(n-1)}$ module?
I can compute it by Weyl character formula but it seems that an
explicit formula is not easy to get.
We can ask similar questions for other type Lie algebra that has diagram automorphism. 
(This question arises when I want to study quiver variety realization of 
symmetrizable type Lie algebras.)
I doubt this question should have been studied before but can not find reference.

Thanks,
Zhijie.